# IsNothing not working as expected in SSRS expression

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2012, ssrs-2016

I have a textbox that contains 2 fields with names in them, but the 2nd field can be empty. If there are 2 names I want it to display like this:

```
[name1], [name2]
```

if there is 1 name I want to display it like this:

```
[name1]
```

I have tried these 2 expressions:

```
=IIF(Fields!name2.Value Is Nothing, "", (", " + Fields!name2.Value))

=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!Joint_Name.Value), "", (", " + Fields!Joint_Name.Value))
```

however, in both cases if the 2nd name is blank it displays:

```
[name1],
```

any ideas how to get rid of that comma?

Comment: Is the field value a NULL or an empty string? IsNothing() works with NULLs but doesn't catch blank/empty string values. Try `IIF(IsNothing(Fields!Joint_Name.Value) OR Fields!Joint_Name.Value = "", ... `

Comment: To expand on Hannover's comment, you may also want to `TRIM` the field in case there's any spaces.  `...OR Trim(Fields!Joint_Name.Value) = "",...`

Comment: I often use something like `LEN(TRIM(Fields!myField.Value))=0` to test for blanks for 'nulls'. Technically not perfect but concise and works for me.

Answer (score 0):

NULLs in your dataset usually come in as "".

```
=IIF(Fields!name2.Value = "", "", (", " + Fields!name2.Value))
```

I always recommend casting your Fields to the data type you intend to work with. A lot of the time the values come through in an unexpected data type and cause script errors.

```
=IIF(CSTR(Fields!name2.Value) = "", "", (", " + CSTR(Fields!name2.Value)))
```